# Convert numpy int to matlab int

Tags: python, matlab, type-conversion, matlab-engine

I'm calling a matlab function in python through matlab engine, and I'm having problems to pass the variables.
I have figured out how to pass some, but for this on I'm getting an error. should be a scalar int.
but when I pass it I got the error:

> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matlab_internal\mlarray_utils.py",
> line 90, in _normalize_size
> if init_dims[0] == 0:
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range

The code works fine If I do not pass the modn variable, so I know that my problem is the conversion type to matlab of this variable.

this is the python code:

```
import numpy  as np
import matlab
import matlab.engine
eng =  matlab.engine.start_matlab()

eng.cd()

Nn = 30
x= 250*np.ones((1,Nn)) 
y= 100*np.ones((1,Nn)) 
z = 32.0
xx = matlab.double(x.tolist())
yy = matlab.double(y.tolist())

f=np.arange(start=0.1,stop=0.66,step=0.1)
modnv=np.concatenate((np.ones((Nn)),2*np.ones((Nn))))

count = 0
for fks in f:
    fks=np.float(0)
    modn = modnv[count]
    modn = modn.astype(int)
    modn = matlab.int8(modn)
    Output = eng.simple_test(xx,yy,z,fks,modn,nargout=4)
    A = np.array(Output[0]).astype(float)
    B = np.array(Output[1]).astype(float)
    C = np.array(Output[2]).astype(float)
    D = np.array(Output[3]).astype(float)
    count = count + 1
```

and this is the matlab function simple_test:

```
function [A,B,C,D] = simple_test(x,y,z,fks,modn)

if modn == 1
    A = 3*x+2*y;
    B = x*ones(length(x),length(x));
    C = ones(z);
    D = x*y';
else
    A = 3*fks;
    B = 3*x+2*y;
    C = A+B;
    D = x*y'
end
```

Does someone know how to overcome that?

Comment: Try removing `nargout` argument from `eng.simple_test()`

Comment: Did you try `modn = matlab.int8([modnv[count]])`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo  I try what you said and I got the error: TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Comment: @Anwarvic I tried, didn't change the error. :(

Comment: Ok, then cast to integer. The key in my comment was putting the value in a list. MATLAB doesn’t know integers, it only knows arrays. Try `modn = matlab.int8([modnv[count].astype(int)])`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get `IndexError: tuple index out of range` error its mostly:

1. Probably one of the indexes is wrong.I suspect you mean to say `[0]` where you say `[1]` and `[1]` where you say `[2]`. Indexes are 0-based in Python.
2. you are passing an array to a function that was expecting a variadic sequence of arguments (eg `'{}{}'.format([1,2]) vs '{}{}'.format(*[1,2]`)

Comment: the error is in a python build-in function, the mlarray_utils.py and is because of the type of input, if was an array with dimension 2 would be ok...   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matlab\_internal\mlarray_utils.py", line 90, in _normalize_size
    if init_dims[0] == 0:

IndexError: tuple index out of range